# Web page to API : Make an API from HTML elements

Tags: javascript, php, html, htmlelements

Is it possible to retrive HTML elements, `div` for example, and make an API from it.

For example, I want to make an API from http://www.tvguide.com/listings/, and take the listings div, and make an API.

I mostly work in PHP, so a PHP answer should be nice (-:

Thanks

Comment: Just google for custom google search (pun intended) and you will find plenty of examples for your kind of problem. :)

Comment: @TobiasKun This is an example, it's not for Google.

Comment: Please add some more info on what you try to achieve.

Comment: @FelixINX: Then see MarkusMüllers question and answer it.

Comment: yes thats totally possible, you can do it in any language, you'll have to try it with the language you are most skilled with and add a question if you get stuck on anything.

Comment: @MarkusMüller Modified.

Comment: @atmd Modified, I mostly work with PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't create an API for a service that is not provided by yourself. What you want to do is extract some information from a webpage. This is called a scraper. Have a look at https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/Goutte

Comment: Ok, but is `scraper` is legal?

Comment: Depends on the service you scrape and the country you are in.